# How can I use docker with pycharm?

Tags: python, docker, pycharm

I want to use docker with pycharm pro,but something confused me.
Here is my Dockerfile ,It worked well:

```
FROM alpine:latest
MAINTAINER Hulei SW-Tech <hulei886@aliyun.com>

RUN set -ex \
    && apk --no-cache update && apk --no-cache upgrade \
    && apk add --no-cache build-base \
                          curl \
                          git \
                          tzdata \
                          bash \
                          linux-headers \
                          libffi-dev \
                          openssl-dev \
                          bzip2-dev \
                          zlib-dev \
                          readline-dev \
                          sqlite-dev \
                          openssh-server \
                          python3-dev \
                          openssl-dev \
                          openssl \
                          libressl \
                          libc-dev \
                          libffi-dev \
                          libxml2-dev \
                          libxml2 \
                          libxslt-dev \
                          openssh-client \
                          openssh-sftp-server \
   && curl -L https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-installer/raw/master/bin/pyenv-installer | bash \
   && echo 'export LANG="zh_CN.UTF-8"' >> /root/.profile \
   && echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.pyenv/bin:$PATH"' >> /root/.profile \
   && echo 'eval "$(pyenv init -)"' >> /root/.profile \
   && echo 'eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"' >> /root/.profile \
   && . /root/.profile \
   && pyenv install 3.7.2 \
   && pyenv global 3.7.2 \
   && pip install pipenv \
   && mkdir -p /app

WORKDIR /app

RUN /root/.pyenv/shims/pipenv install requests \
                                  beautifulsoup4 \
                                  pymongo \
                                  scrapy \
                                  scrapyd

ENTRYPOINT ["/root/.pyenv/shims/pipenv","run"]
```

When I use this Dockerfile to buid a image,then I select this image to be my remote python interupter,but something wrong like this:
[image: setting docker as my remote python interupter]

[image: Error Message]

How can I fix this? I need some help!

Comment: PyCharm tries to build the container and fails to find `python` executable there. Replace "Python interpreter path" with an existing executable, perhaps `python3` or with a whole path to it.

Comment: @PavelKarateev Thanks a lot! I fix my problem in your way.